# reference a double resource inside another double resource

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I would like to reference a resource of Double inside another Double resource,
something like this:

`<sys:Double x:Key="width">100</sys:Double>`

`<sys:Double x:Key="height">{StaticResource width}</sys:Double>`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is possible, you are referencing an atomic data-type that can contain nothing else than a numeric value which is neither a field nor a property. To allow that you probably need to create your own datatype.

**Edit:** Normally you should be able to use a [`DynamicResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx) for this:

```
<DynamicResource x:Key="height" ResourceKey="width"/>
```

(*Visual Studio won't like this but it should compile and work*)

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm not sure the example you're giving could work, since i'm not able to do a binding to "sys:Double".

but other than that, the answer to you question:
you can use a convertor, and it's pretty simple.
add this class:

```
class DoubleConvertor : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and than reference this class in the xaml (make sure to use the xmlns of your project first):

```
<local:DoubleConvertor x:Key="DoubleConvertor" />
```

now in your binding you can do something like:

```
<UserControl Height="{Binding path={StaticResource width}, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConvertor} />
```

Comment: This converter is unnecessary, as it doesn't actually convert the value. It would only be necessary if (for example) you wanted to have height be 2*width.